# How do I get a web page to display all content within any screen size?

Tags: html, css

I have a webpage which can be found at www.navinmistry.co.uk. 
I want this page to display all the content in any screen size.
at the moment it is set in pixels, would this be a case of changing it percentages instead?

Comment: No need to ask this question here. Just use google.

Comment: Yes, Google [Responsive Web Design Tutorials](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=responsive+web+design+tutorial&oq=responsive+web+design+tutorial).

Comment: Yeah responsive design, look up on how that works. Don't forget to add the meta tags and actually test it on mobile devices.
On a side note, why so much hate, SO users? Its a genuine question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, make it 100% width.
Using percentages would accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

For all elements to be shown "good" in any size browser window I suggest using [twitter bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), than you just use Grid Layout system and put element according to it:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
   <div class="col-xs-5">Width = 100 / 12 * 5</div>
   <div class="col-xs-7">Width = 100 / 12 * 7</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using percentages you could achieve a nice display on any screen, but this is fairly hard to do. For example what do I do if the screen is too small to display all the menus on the top, (on a phone for example) ?
Hopefully some css frameworks exist to make your life easier ! : )

For example you could try to use [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)